# How to make a part of my code accessible to multiple Activities

Tags: android, interface

I have the following code that is used to make the status bar transparent and i'm using it on most of my activities. Since it doesn't look good or seem efficient to write that same code every time, i thought about creating an `Interface` that each Activity can implement but i run into an issue where the `Interface` couldn't find the `setWindowFlag()` method. Is an `Interface` the right way to make a part of code accessible to multiple classes or should i follow another approach? If it is the right way, what can i do about the `setWindowFlag()` method?

code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a BaseActivity with this method in onCreate (and probably other new later), and make each activity inherite from BaseActivity

Comment: Alright, i'm just getting `NullPointerException` stating that i'm calling `getWindow()` on a null object reference which seems logical. I tried using `getParent().getWindow()` but same thing. How can i get the calling activity? Using `getCallingActivity().getWindow()` says that it can't resolve `getWindow()`

Comment: Put your code in a method, and call this method in each child activity

Comment: Awesome, i made some tweaks and it works like a charm, thank you. One last question, is a `BaseActivity` frequently used in cases like this, because i've seen various people use the same name but didn't know what it was.

Comment: I often use BaseActivity in my app to manage toolbar, menu, other common code... it's a better coding principle